# FutureBuilder not working inside ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

i have FutureBuilder and ListView I want to show the bottom of some was one page after downloading JSON they appear as one piece.
I added FutureBuilder inside ListView
can't appear FutureBuilder and i have error in console

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#e0a8a relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `shrinkwrap` and `physics` under `ListView.builder`

```
ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: ScrollPhysics(),
itemCount: rodios.length,

)
```

Comment: I don't know what happened but it worked for me. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ListView is in a container that has sizes:

```
Container(width: double.infinity, height: double.infinity, child: ListView...)
```

Comment: Same problem, I think it needs to re-adjust the height after downloading

Comment: To be honest, people could help you more if you share the code.